# Problems to map a json with axios.get

Tags: json, reactjs, axios

My name is Jose and i'm trying to fetch data Json in an array to be displayed with react. My json file is:

```
[{"nid":"460","title":"Prueba local","parent":"null"},
{"nid":"458","title":"Otra prueba","parent":"null"}...
```

My js file is:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios'
import './index.css';

class Ramas extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    axios
      .get('../proceso.json')
      .then(({ data })=> {
        this.setState({ 
          data
        });
      })
      .catch((err)=> {console.log('no recibido')})
  }
```

I do not get any results. I appreciate any help.

My folder structure:
react_root
-nodemodules
-public
--index.html
-src
--index.js

The json file is in vps.../fuentes/proceso.json. It's another server an i can access to it via url

Thank you

Comment: Will you please share the folder structure and where the proceso.json is placed ?

Comment: My folder structure:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need of `axios` for this,

The real use of `axios` is when you want to fetch data from API or out of your server , if `proceso.js` was on a different server then its good to use.

---

What you can do is create one file ;

```
// proceso.js

export default [
    {"nid":"460","title":"Prueba local","parent":"null"},
    {"nid":"458","title":"Otra prueba","parent":"null"}
    ...
]
```

Then use it like :

```
import proceso from 'path/to/proceso.js';

componentDidMount(){
  this.setState({ 
    data : proceso
  });
}
```

---

If your json file is being updated by server then put the file inside public folder and then try to call axios via public folder path,

Because once the build is generated, you will not be able to access other directories, like src directory

Comment: Thank you Vivek, but my json file must be update by another server in production and i must use the axios. Excuse me by my imprecision.